# Connecting a branch to another branch in git?

Tags: git, github, repository, branch, git-branch

I have a master branch I want to make dist branch that tracking all changes in the dist folder in master branch in my Github repository.

Can I do it?

Comment: Do you want a separate branch that is the sole branch making changes to the dist folder, and merge it back to master at some point? If so, just create a branch off master, and only make changes to dist when in that branch.

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452) and then decide what **you** mean by *branch* before you proceed.